Littlewood's Theorem For Arithmetic Progressions
A celebrated theorem of Littlewood states that the function $\pi(x)-\text{li}(x)$ changes signs infinitely many often, where $\pi(x)$ and $\text{li}(x)$ are the familiar prime counting and logarithmic integral functions. This result was quite surprising because for small values of $x$ it was conjectured that $\pi(x)<\text{li}(x)$ holds always. The numbers that violate this inequality have been extensively studies, see Skewes numbers. Of course by prime number theorem on arithmetic progression $\pi(x;q,a)$ is asymptotic to $\frac{1}{\varphi(q)}\text{li}(x)$ where $(q,a)=1$ and $\pi(x;q,a)$ counts primes that are $\equiv a \bmod q$. My question is there a similar theorem for the difference $\pi(x;q,a)-\frac{1}{\varphi(q)}\text{li}(x)$? Is it known if this function changes signs infinitely many times or are there estimates for the violations?

Look up Chebyshev's bias.

Yeah but thats for the signs of $\pi(x;q,a)-\pi(x;q,b)$. I don't think that $\pi(x;q,a)\sim\pi(x;q,b)\sim\frac{1}{\varphi(q)}\text{li}(x)$ implies the sign change of $\pi(x;q,a)-\frac{1}{\varphi(q)}\text{li}(x)$.

Look at the methods involved.

This is indeed related to Chebyshev's bias, as pointed by P. Humphries. However, I believe the result is not known unconditionally.
In the paper Chebyshev’s conjecture and the prime number race by Ford and Konyagin, it is stated that under the "Haselgrove condition", that is, if no Dirichlet $L$-function modulo $q$ vanish on the real line between $0$ and $1$, then $\pi(x;q,a)-\pi(x;q,b)$ changes sign infinitely often, a result due to Knapowski and Turán. You may want to have a look at that paper and also at [KT] to see if this applies to the quantity $\pi(x;q,a) - \frac{1}{\varphi(q)} \mathrm{li}(x)$ (which I'm willing to bet it does).
[KT] S. Knapowski and P. Turán, Comparative prime number theory I. Acta. Math. Sci.Hungar. 13 (1962)
